# How to get all lists in a site collection along with their Guid and URL

Tags: powershell

I've created a Powershell script to get all the lists in my site with their Guids. This is working but I also want the script to the return the URL.

```
$_.Lists | ForEach-Object {Write-host "List:"$_.Title ":"$_.Id > C:\Guids.csv}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return any property on the SPList object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist_members.aspx).  The closest I think that would give you what you want is the DefaultViewUrl property.  So $_.DefaultViewUrl.